# I need to find the proper 301 redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having trouble with a 301 redirect.  I've tried a few but they are not working as I need it.

I have an old website that no longer exists, I would like to forward the entire domain to a landing page on my new website.

So when someone types in www.olddomain.com I want them to go to www.newdomain.com/landingpage.php

The problem is that I want ALL requests on the old domain to go to that landing page.  Currently I have the domain forwarded thru GoDaddy, and when someone (or Google) types in www.olddomain.com/whateverpage.htm or forwards it to www.newdomain.com/landingpage.php/whateverpage.htm

This is causing issues with Google indexing.

So I need a redirect that will send ALL requests of ANY page at www.olddomain.com/ to www.newdomain.com/landingpage.php

What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule on DocumentRoot of old site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/landingpage.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: At first this didn't work, but then I took the / out after landingpage.php and it works.  Now it says: RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/landingpage.php? [R=301,L]   -  Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a LAMP stack (linux server, MySQL, PHP) you can use rewrite rules in an .htaccess file to capture all requests to www.newdomain.com/landingpage.php* and redirect them back to landingpage.php. If you're hosting on a Windows server, you can do these sort of redirect rules with the URL Rewrite module in IIS (which can import .htaccess rules).

Comment: My site is hosted on GoDaddy with the Linux software option.  So I assume a redirect in the .htaccess file is the best way to go.  The problem is that the redirects I have tried have not worked like I need.  That is what's causing the problem that I mentioned in the first post.

Comment: Yep! To not send you down a bad path, you're looking for rewrite rules. Here's a reference to get you going: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

Comment: I'm at such a loss with this.  Would this work?  Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newdomain.com/landingpage.php [R=301,L]